# Django and ajax image file upload errors and csrf

Tags: ajax, django

I tried out [Alex Kuhl's ajax script](http://kuhlit.blogspot.com/2011/04/ajax-file-uploads-and-csrf-in-django-13.html) to upload images to Django 1.4.

My first question is why I'm getting an empty page with firebug telling me I have an error:

In my template html:

```
$ is not defined
element: $('#file-uploader')[0],
```

Here is my entire html file for it:
http://pastebin.com/NjbV5gMn

My second question is why the ajax code uses `{{ csrf_token }}` instead of `{% csrf_token %}`. But if I use `{% csrf_token %}`, I get the firebug error:

```
missing } after property list

'csrf_token': '<div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='Cx0zFFak6OLgrHiAnFa3k4BPDmn4BgoT' /></div>',
```

EDIT: I changed the element to `document.getElementById('file-uploader')` and it seems to work, so I think I've solved my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, `$` is introduced by jQuery library, you need to load it before the usage. (or use `document.getElementById('file-uploader')` which is equivalent to `$('#file-uploader')[0]`)

For the second question, the javascript line expects a csrf token, which could be introduced through `{{ csrf_token }}`, instead of a div tag including an input field w/ csrf token as its value, which the `{% csrf_token %}` does.

For `{{ csrf_token }}` to work, check the 3rd step in [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it), add `'django.core.context_processors.csrf'` into your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` and use `RequestContext` in your view.